# Storing a .pem file in MySql

Tags: mysql, certificate, pem

I have a form and I need to upload a .pem file through a restful webservice. I see that in my requisition the field for the file is actually the hash of the certificate. I can save all other informations in the db of the webservice, but the field for the file is always "null".

What is the appropriate type for storing this hash? I already tried Blob and LongText, Varchar, etc

tnx in advance

Answer (score 3):

PEM format is text ( base 64 encoding with `------BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` headers). You would need a long  VARCHAR to store it. A hash is binary format so you need a BLOB

But a hash has a small size. For example 20 bytes for SHA1 and 32 bytes for SHA256. Depending on your storage you can use a fixed length VARCHAR converting the binary value to HEX ( size x2) or BASE64 (size x 1,33)